# Should I use 2 ListViews or 2 Adapters with 1 ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

When it comes to a screen that contains 2 different lists depending on the state of say a checkbox at the top, is it better to use 2 listviews that you hide/show when the checkbox is selected or should I have 2 different adapters and attach/detach each from a single listview?
Are there any benefits/downsides to either of these solutions?

Comment: Does hiding a listview prevent a user from clicking on its items?

Answer (score 0):

You should go with 2 adapters and 1 ListView. the reason is simple - either way you are going to have 2 Adapters (as per your question). Having one ListView would make the code simpler and there will only be a single instance in your xml file. Depending upon the state of the checkbox, you just need to change the adapter the listview points to and notify of this change.

If you had two list views, you would have to hide one. Just because the ListView is hidden doesn't mean that Android does not have to bother about it. You just have an object (size will depend) consuming resources sitting in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the proposals are wrong.

If we assume that you have same Object type to be listed in a ListView (Let's say a user object with name and id fields), then you need to have one ListView and one Adapter. When user wants to switch the data, what you need to do is to send the new data set to your adapter and then refresh it by calling `notifyDataSetChanged();` method of adapter.